# I need records from a database not created by my application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on an application to organize bookmarks. I know the bookmarks are located in `/data/data/com.android.browser/databases`, however there seems to be a problem querying a database outside of an application. In order to populate my listview with android's default browser bookmark database it appears I need to implement a "Content-Provider." Is there a better way to access these records? Is there a Content-Provider specific to this cause?

For anyone starting out with sqlite3 databases there is an excellent example here: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/55.html

Comment: Just found this link explaining the content provider again. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2337085/1157215

Also found http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/package-summary.html 

a list of content_providers that allow access to different information, bookmarks included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Browser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html) content provider. Specifically, to deal with bookmarks you have to use the [BOOKMARKS_URI](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#BOOKMARKS_URI).

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I would begin to do that?

Comment: My mistake, I need to shut up and use my google more. Thanks dtmilano.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004331/android-bookmark-contentprovider-makes-bookmark-but-not-visible-in-browsers-boo